# Does R works for multilingual data

Tags: r, multilingual

We have prepared machine learning algorithms like clasification algorithm having features as factors. Topic modelling on text data for which text data is in English

Below script which is prepared .

```
  complete <- subset(complete,select=c(Group,Type,Text,Target))

  data <- complete$Text
  corpus <-tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
  toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) { return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
  removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",x)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "/")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "-")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, ":")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, ";")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "@")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "\\(" )
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, ")")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, ",")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "_")
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeSpecialChars))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus,stemDocument)
  tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

  train1 <- as.matrix(tdm)
  complete1 <- subset(complete,select=c(Group,Type,Target))
  complete1 <- Filter(function(x)(length(unique(x))>1), complete1)
  train <- cbind(complete1, train1)
  train$Text <- NULL

  train$Target <- as.factor(train$Target)

  ############################################################################################
  #                       Model Run
  ############################################################################################
  fit <-svm(Target ~ ., data = train)

  termlist <- list(dictionary = Terms(tdm))
  retval <- list(model = fit, termlist = termlist, complete = complete)
  saveRDS(retval, "./modelTarget.rds")
```

Now we will be expecting data in another languages - Chinese/Korean/Japanese/French/Portugese/Spanish .

Wanted to check if R support these types of data especially for text cleaning. 
Please advice

Comment: If you use linux, there should not be too much of a problem so long as you use UTF encoding consistently. But I'm not sure if there are many packages specifically for processing other languages.

Comment: The documentation for `tm` when describing the stopwords function says "Supported languages are danish, dutch, english, finnish, french, german, hungarian, italian, norwegian, portuguese, russian, spanish, and swedish" That includes just a couple of the languages that you list. Unicode itself isn't a problem, but for text mining which goes beyond mere pattern matching you will need to find an appropriate package to deal with non-European languages such as Korean.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you very much for information. will try to find an appropriate package to deal with non-European languages